# util.promisify not a function node 8

Tags: linux, node.js, promise

**Проблема**

```
vpotseluyko@localhost:~/PhpstormProjects/easta-api$ node -v
v8.0.0
```

Код:

```
const redis = require('redis');
const util = require('util');
const client = redis.createClient();
client.get = util.promisify(client.get);
```

Вывод:

```
util.promisify is not a function
```

Согласно документации: https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original

**Что делал**

```
rm -rf node_modules && npm i
```

Comment: Ос - федора 25. Нода собиралась из исходников с помощью nvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не надо ставить node 8 с помощью nvm. Сборка проходит некорректно по непонятным причинам. Ставьте с сайта.

```
sudo tar -C /usr/local --strip-components 1 -xJf Downloads/node-v8.0.0-linux-x64.tar.xz
```